# heatmap in black/white loses bars

Tags: r

When using R's default

```
heatmap(mymatrix,labRow=names, labCol=FALSE)
```

where matrix consists of 0's and 1's, I get a correct representation of 0's as dark red and 1's as yellow or some lighter shade of red. However, if I use col=grey(seq(0,1)) or grey(seq(1,0), the last two rows consistently have the 1-valued bars blanked out. Has anybody encountered this problem before, and is there a simple fix?

Comment: Would you mind including an example? I wonder if specifying the grey color palette and changing the values for the start and end of the palette would help? I can't seem to really reproduce the problem though. 

   
`test=matrix(rbinom(100,1,0.5),ncol=10,nrow=10);
heatmap(test, col=grey.colors(20, start=0.2, end=0.8))`

Comment: Using decimal valued colors solves the problem. For some reason, even though all matrix values are 0/1, some of the "1" values are shaded darker than others, so that with a color 0/1 scale they get "rounded" to black or white.

Comment: Nice! Glad you figured it out.